# Changes to forceSimulation disable drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have modified [Bostock's force direct graph example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) to produce the layout I want by adding labels and changing some of the forceSimulation parameters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="urf-8"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  d3.json("http://localhost/mail/bostock/getneighborhood.php?contact=5244", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });


  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".32em")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "8px")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(150).strength(1))
    .force("collide",d3.forceCollide( function(d){return d.r + 8 }).iterations(16) )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

The only problem is the drag functions no longer work.  Can anyone suggest how to fix?

Comment: Sorry, missed your reply to the earlier question.  I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code you'll see that you have **two** variables named `simulation`. One of them outside `d3.json`...

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

... and the other one inside `d3.json`:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    }).distance(150).strength(1))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 8
    }).iterations(16))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

The simulation that moves the nodes is the inside one. However, due to the function scope, the drag functions are referring to the outside variable.

**solution**: keep just one simulation, *outside* `d3.json`.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you very much!